# Erasing records with for loops

Tags: smart-contract, table

if I want to erase a table:

```
orderbook b(_self, _self.value);
auto m = b.get_index<name("idxprod")>();
for (auto &i : m) {
    m.erase(i);
}
```

I get the error:

> Error 3160005: The table operation is not allowed Error Details:
>   dereference of deleted object

but if I try it like this:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end();) {
    i = m.erase(i);
}
```

it seems to work. so my question is: **why does one work but not the other?**

and another thing I notice is that `for (auto i : m)` doesn't work... it complains:

> assertion failure with message: object passed to erase is not in
>   multi_index

which I guess means that whatever the first form of `for` is calling returns a reference.  interestingly `for (auto &i = m.begin()` doesn't work either as the left value needs to be a constant, but if I `for (const auto &i =`, then it complains about the reassignment `i = m.erase(i)`

grr...

*** Appendix I ***

this also doesn't work:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end();) {
    m.erase(i);
    i++;
}
```

nor does the more normative:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++) {
    m.erase(i);
}
```

but curiously this does:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end();) {
    m.erase(i++);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with erasing in a for loop is that **you are editing the structure you are iterating over**. This is not an EOS specific error.

Your first for loop creates one iterator and tries to run over your data structure. If you delete something now **the references are broken**. The iterator is not correctly updated and stored.

Your second suggestion is running because `erase` will return a **correct referenced iterator and you are saving it** to `i = m.erase(i);`. Also In **every new iteration** you check if the end conditions are matched which will always **check for the correct last iterator element** `i != m.end();`.

I would also suggest to take a look at my thread **[Delete all multi_index records without iterator?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/delete-all-multi-index-records-without-iterator)** because if your `multi_index` is too large you won't be able to delete it anymore because the transaction time limit kicks in.

Comment: that, my friend, is called prescience.  I'm already running into a deadline exception: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/exception-details-3080006-deadline-exception-transaction-took-too-long -- reading your solution to deletions....

Answer (score 1):

I use this helper function whenever I need to reset a table (mainly during development):

```
template<typename T>
void erase_all(T& table) {
  auto itr = table.begin();
  while(itr != table.end()) {
    itr = table.erase(itr);
  }
}
```

Usage: Let's say there is a table named `file` that you want to delete, simply call:

```
erase_all(file)
```

As mentioned by others, this will only work as long as the table contains a limited number of items as often during development.