# Exception Details: 3080006 deadline_exception: Transaction took too long

Tags: smart-contract, cpu

I'm getting this error and have read all there is to read on the net (which isn't much) about it.  mostly I see others complaining about this error when they run an action *for the first time*

in my case, it simply won't run, and I think it's a question of data size.  I added records to one of my tables and now it breaks.  I don't have a lot of records in there, 8 test records to be precise, so I don't think that's the really the problem.  if it is I'm in trouble because in production I'm likely to have much larger numbers

the problem I'm experiencing is on a local net run on a MacBook Pro and I'm wondering:

1. if I need to optimise the code within the action to minimise the time it consumes, are there guidelines?
2. is there a way to measure the time that specific pieces of code are taking (profiling)?
3. do I need to increase my CPU, and if so, how (I've not found anything about this)?
4. what considerations do I need to keep in mind when releasing on the mainnet?

any other thoughts or advice on this complicated subject would be great

Comment: What do you want to read on the table? Could you include some code? If you don't need to read it in the contract, you could also use the RPC API to read some data from your contract.

Comment: I didn't mention reading anything from a table and the problem doesn't have to do with that.  it's that the transaction is taking too long to complete

Comment: Ah, ok sorry. I misunderstood your first sentence. Did the tips in **[Delete all multi_index records without iterator?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/delete-all-multi-index-records-without-iterator)** work for you or does it help to solve your problem?

Comment: yes, the notion of deferring transactions solved my problem but I'm leaving this open as it requests a broader perspective on dealing with these issues