# How to loop a multi_index table in a smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, eosio.cdt

I have very simple table `items` with the following structure:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] item
   {
       uint64_t id;
       uint64_t state;
       string description;

       uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
       uint64_t by_state() const { return state; }
   };

   typedef eosio::multi_index<"items"_n, item,
       eosio::indexed_by<"bystate"_n, eosio::const_mem_fun<item, uint64_t, &item::by_state>>> items;
    items items_table;
```

and I have an action within smart contract, where I need to filter the items by particular state and loop the result executing a simple processing for each of the filtered items. Currently I am using the following implementation (simply looping the whole table, searching for the items on specified state):

```
for (auto iter = items_table.begin(); iter != items_table.end(); iter++)
{
   if (iter->state == state)
   {
       // handle item record
       ...
   }

}
```

but it is not sufficient if table contains enormous amount of items.

Does anyone knows is there a way (is EOS) to fetch the item records on specified state using secondary index "bystate" and further loop those records and apply another logic for each of them ?

Answer (score 1):

With your current setup, you could do something like this to optimize things a bit:

```
items_table items(_self, _self.value);

auto idx = items.get_index<"bystate"_n>();
auto itr_start = idx.lower_bound(name("pending").value);
auto itr_end = idx.upper_bound(name("pending").value);

for (itr_start != itr_end; itr_start++)
{
       // handle item record (they should all be of state "pending")
}
```

However, you still have to be aware of the transaction time limit as mentioned above.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing for the loop `for (;itr_start != itr_end; itr_start++)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common question, because the **transaction time limit** is going to kick in. At the moment I am using **deferred transactions** to trigger a search action that takes an additional argument.

You could also **save the state of your search in another table** as well.

I discussed this in a thread with the deletion of elements, you can adapt the code to use it to search.

**[Delete all multi_index records without iterator?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/delete-all-multi-index-records-without-iterator)**